# Cannot read property 'axios' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, npm

i install axios :
`npm install axios`
and import it :
`import axios from "axios";`
this is part of my code :
`

```
  const fetchDataHandler=useCallback(()=>{
        setLoading(true);
        setCity("");
        axios({
            method:"GET",
            url:`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${api.key}`
        }).then(res=>{
            console.log(res.data)
        });
    },[api.key,city])
```

`
when i try to get data from api i have this error
please help

i tried to install latest version to axios but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure you want to use:

var axios = require('axios');

not import axios from "axios" when using node.js.

Source: Postman.com